# How to convert my java complex object into spark dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I am using java spark and below is my code

```
JavaRDD<MyComplexEntity> myObjectJavaRDD = resultJavaRDD.flatMap(result -> result.getMyObjects());

DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myObjectJavaRDD, MyComplexEntity.class);

df.saveAsParquetFile("s3a://mybucket/test.parquet");
```

MyComplexEntity.java

```
public MyComplexEntity implements Serializable {
     private Identifier identifier;
     private boolean isSwitch1True;
     private String note;
     private java.util.ArrayList<Identifier> secodaryIds;
     ......
}
```

Identifier.java

```
public Identifier implements Serializable {
     private int id;
     private String uuid;
     ......
}
```

The issue is I failed at step 2 when creating dataframe from myObjectJavaRDD. How can I convert a list of complex java objects to a data frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway, you could convert this to Scala ?

Scala supports `case class` for this kind of situation

For your case the challenge is you have a `Seq/Array` of `Inner` case class as => `private java.util.ArrayList<Identifier> secodaryIds;`

So it could be done in following way

```
// inner case class Identifier
case class Identifier(Id : Integer , uuid : String)
val innerVal = Seq(Identifier(1,"gsgsg"),Identifier(2,"dvggwgwg"))

// Outer case class MyComplexEntity
case class MyComplexEntity(notes : String, identifierArray : Seq[Identifier])
val outerVal = MyComplexEntity("Hello", innerVal)
```

please note **=>**

outerVal : MyComplexEntity contains a **LIST** of Identifier Objects as shown below

`outerVal: MyComplexEntity = MyComplexEntity(Hello,List(Identifier(1,gsgsg), Identifier(2,dvggwgwg)))`

Now the actual **spark way** of doing it using **Dataset**

```
import spark.implicits._
// Convert Our Input Data in Same Structure as your MyComplexEntity
// Only Trick is To 'Reflect' A Seq[(Int,String)] => Seq[Identifier]
// Hence we have to do 2 Mapping once for Outer Case class (MyComplexEntity) And Once For Inner Seq of Identifier
// If We Just Take this Input Data and Convert To DataSet ( without any Schema Inference)
// This is How It looks 

val inputData = Seq(("Some DAY",Seq((210,"wert67"),(310,"bill123"))),
                    ("I WILL BE", Seq((420,"henry678"),(1000,"baba123"))),
                    ("Saturday Night",Seq((1000,"Roger123"),(2000,"God345")))
                    )
                    
val unMappedDs = inputData.toDS
```

gives us **=>**

```
// See how it is Infered
// unMappedDs: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Seq[(Int, String)])] = [_1: string, _2: array<struct<_1:int,_2:string>>]
```

But If We map it **'correctly' =>**

As **=>** `// Second element is a Seq[(Int,String)] and We map it into Seq[Identifier] as x._2.map(y => Identifier(y._1,y._2))`

Like Below :

```
val resultDs = inputData.toDS.map(x =>MyComplexEntity(x._1,x._2.map(y => Identifier(y._1,y._2))))
resultDs.show(20,false)
```

We get a Structure like **=>**

`resultDs: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyComplexEntity] = [notes: string, identifierArray: array<struct<Id:int,uuid:string>>]`

And Data As :

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|notes         |identifierArray                 |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|Some DAY      |[[210,wert67], [310,bill123]]   |
|I WILL BE     |[[420,henry678], [1000,baba123]]|
|Saturday Night|[[1000,Roger123], [2000,God345]]|
+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

That easy using Scala.
Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, @SanBan.  However, I cannot choose which way to go. I am building on top of the legacy code, which is written by Java. Anyway I can achieve this using java? Or there is no way as far as you know? Thanks again.

Comment: Just use the `map(x =>MyComplexEntity(x._1,x._2.map(y => Identifier(y._1,y._2))))` in Java Syntax.
And Please Upvote If You Like The Answer :-)